# Add JDK in Linux to run IDEA

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new in Linux & read a lot solution about add JDK in Ubuntu but not work! :/
I want to install JDK in Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04-i386 and downloaded JDK 8 and add `"/home/user/Soft/jdk1.8.0_20/bin"` to `"/etc/enviroment"`.

I run IntelliJ IDEA 13 (Community Edition) well, also write some project but after some day when I want lunch it,it says:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather > than JRE.

I installed `java-7-openjdk-i386` with Software Center and add "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386" in "/etc/enviroment" but still saying that.

What can I do?

Comment: How about you try setting the `JAVA_HOME` as it suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you mean when saying "add", but I would suggest you just adding some lines into `/etc/environment`. What you need to do is modify `PATH`, specified in this file this way (I assume you use system-installed Java):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin"
```

Also, you have to add `JAVA_HOME` enviroment variable definition in this file:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/"
```

So, finally your file should like like

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/"
```

If you want to manage Java installation yourself, you should use `"/home/kaaveh/Soft/jdk1.8.0_20"` instead of "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/" in the code above.

After all these actions, you may need to restart your DE, so log out and then log in back.